# WebSphere and Axis 1.4 - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, axis, websphere-8

in my application I have to call a webService using axis-1.4 libraries.
With axis-1.4.jar inside my application I get the following error:

```
Exception data: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.apache.axis.message.SOAPEnvelope (initialization failure)
```

This means (I think) that my jar conflicts with other libs in server (anyway I'm using Parent_Last class loading)
If I try to remove axis-1.4.jar from my ear, I get the following:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants
```

Does anyone knows which library is in conflict with axis-1.4.jar?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can easily find it yourself looking in RAD (if you have it) which JAR contains that classes. You can also try creating a shared library and third option: Extracting the classes you need from the library.

Comment: I haven't RAD and I can't exctract libraries